# How to reuse the same TInterfacedObject instance on the same scope in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have implemented a bitmap adapter to extent bitmap functionality as follow:

```
unit UBitmapHelper;

IBmpUtils = interface
  procedure SomeNewRoutine;
end;

TBitmapUtilsAdapter = class (TInterfacedObject, IBmpUtils)
public
  constructor Create (ABitmap: TBitmap);
  //IBmpUtils
  procedure SomeNewRoutine;
end;

TBitmapHelper = class helper for TBitmap
  function Utils: IBmpUtils; //method factory pattern
end;

function TBitmapHelper.Utils: IBmpUtils;
begin
  Result := TBitmapUtilsAdapter.Create(Self);
end;
```

so I now can use this adapter as follow:

```
uses UBitmapHelper;

procedure Test;  
var
  MyBitmap: TBitmap;
  i: Integer;
begin
  MyBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  MyBitmap.SetSize(50, 50);
  for i := 1 to 100 do
    MyBitmap.Utils.SomeNewRoutine;
  FreeAndNil(MyBitmap);  
end;
```

I don't need to free Utils as my adapter inherited from TInterfacedObject so it will be automatically freed when go out Test procedure scope, fine! but maybe there is a little performance problem.

**Does the compiler create a new Utils instance for each iteration or it is smart enough in this case to reuse the same Utils instance while it's in the same scope?**

Obviously I can get the instance before the for-loop then use it inside but I am trying to find out how to use the notation MyBitmap.Utils.SomeNewRoutine anywhere without a big deal with performance. **Is any way to do it?**

Note: I am using Delphi 10.3

**Edit**

To be more clear:

1. I am enforced to implement IBmpUtils interface so I can't use neither record nor helper classes. I am also enforced not to create my own TBitmap descendent class then implement the IBmpUtils interface so my only solution would be the adapter.
2. I want to keep all utilities under a "namespace", e.g. MyBitmap.**Utils**.SomeNewRoutine.
3. I want to use the "notation" MyBitmap.Utils.XYZ everywhere without worry about create/destroy instances.

**Is there any way to accomplish this without a performance penalty like one described above (i.e use the notation inside a loop)?**

Comment: If you add `ShowMessage('ctor')` to `TBitmapUtilsAdapter.Create` you will find that it is executed 100 times.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand so there is no way to implement this kind of "notation" without a performance impact? With "notation" I mean keeping all functionality together under the same object but without manage (create/destroy) that object at all.

Comment: Is the goal to be able to write `bm.Utils.SomeProcA`, `bm.Utils.SomeProcB` etc. for any `TBitmap` value `bm`?

Comment: Yes, it is! I want to write that from everywhere without worry about create/destroy instance but obviously without any performance risk.

Comment: then you need no class instance, static procedures or class helper like Andreas showed you is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @whosrdaddy but I need to implement IBmpUtils interface so I can't do it with a record or a helper class :(

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, it turns out that the main goal is to be able to write things like `bm.Utils.SomeProcA`, `bm.Utils.SomeProcB` for every `TBitmap` value `bm`, with as little overhead (performance penalty) as possible. My first idea would be to try

```
type
  TBitmapUtils = record
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
  public
    procedure MyProc1;
    procedure MyProc2;
  end;

  TBitmapHelper = class helper for TBitmap
    function Utils: TBitmapUtils; inline;
  end;
```

where

```
{ TBitmapUtils }

procedure TBitmapUtils.MyProc1;
begin
  ShowMessageFmt('The width of the bitmap is %d.', [FBitmap.Width]);
end;

procedure TBitmapUtils.MyProc2;
begin
  ShowMessageFmt('The height of the bitmap is %d.', [FBitmap.Height]);
end;

{ TBitmapHelper }

function TBitmapHelper.Utils: TBitmapUtils;
begin
  Result.FBitmap := Self;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, it is the goal BUT I need keeping the adapter which must be a class because I am enforced to implement the IBmpUtils interface. I just reduced the problem to show it in a simple way. It seems there is no way to achieve the goal with classes :(

Comment: @Delmo: And I assume it would not be OK to create a new class that derives from `TBitmap`?

Comment: that's correct! I can't create a new descendent class so I want to use an adapter. It seems difficult to achieve the goal under all these conditions!